# How to check if VBA application is in focus when GetAsyncKeyState is pressed

Tags: vba

I have a long running application written in VBA. Because it runs for a long time I call a sub from the main loop every iteration to check if the user has pressed the escape key. The sub is listed below. The code works great except that it is always listening, even when the VBA application does not have the focus. What's the best way to approach this? Is there an alternative to GetAsyncKeyState which only listens when the correct application is in focus, or are there system calls I can use to check that the correct window is in focus.

```
Private Sub checkForUserEscKeyAbort()
    'Listen for escape key and exit gracefully if user aborts.
    Dim abortResult As VbMsgBoxResult
    If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyEscape) Then
        abortResult = MsgBox("Escape key pressed, do you want to abort?", vbYesNo)
        If abortResult = vbYes Then Call teardownSLICER
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If your "application" is a userform you can set the "'Cancel" property of a button to true. This automatically "maps" the cancel action to this Buttons Click event, which you can handle in the codebehind of the Userform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way GetAsyncKeyState operates.  It does more than just check it the key is currently down, it also checks if the key was pressed since the last time GetAsyncKeyState was called.  Thus, your problem of "always listening".

You could use GetKeyState, but frankly, I'm not a fan of that option either.  Your code must be well crafted to avoid a polling window that is so small that you literally have to hold the key down to ensure it isn't missed.

A viable alternative is key masking where you use a combination of keys such as Shift-Escape.  There is a decent introduction to this (and many other subjects) on [Chip Pearson's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/keytest.aspx) site.  However, this is still not my preferred method.

My preference has already mentioned in the comments.  Your application may best be improved with a user form.  It also gives you the ability to get information in front of the user.  Perhaps they wouldn't try quitting the application if a progress bar on the user form indicated 95% completion.  Maybe you can add a pause button that free's some resources for a prescient need and then resumes when the user is ready.  That little extra functionality on its own is enough to win me over but there is an even better reason for using a User Form - it does exactly what you asked!

User forms, and many user form controls, have Keydown, Keyup, and Keypress events that only trigger when the form (or control) have focus.  This is precisely what you wanted.